Select polygon (and create submesh) by color of texture?
For a procedural unity mesh operation:
What is a performant way to  select polygon (and create submesh) by color of texture?
Raycast hit a point on the mesh, then paint bucket search for the same color to segment by color?

It sounds like you have a feasible plan. How are the results when you implement this plan?

Issues with the paintfill selection.

What are those issues? Consider editing your question to explain in more detail, or include sample images demonstrating the problem.
